# Is there a build in function that calculates eigenvectors in Julia

Tags: matrix, vector, linear-algebra, equation, eigenvector

I would like to find the eigenvector q of following equation: 
Q * q = 0 
where Q  is a square matrix with known values.

Like shown in the image below I used an example where I already calculated q.

[image]

I thought that the function `eigvecs()` would calculate the vector q and not a new sqaure matrix.

[image]

Is there another function or perhaps a different way to calculate q?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eigenvectors are not uniquely defined.

If u is an eigenvector of Q corresponding to eigenvalue a (0 in your case) then for any non-zero scalar x x*u is also an eigenvector of Q corresponding to the same eigenvalue.

If you look at the third column of eigvecs(Q) above, you will see that it is (1/2 1/3 1/6) scaled by ~ 1.603568

Comment: how did you know that it was scaled by 1.603568?

Comment: Well I thought one of them had to be q scaled by something amd the third one was the obvious candidate as its third component looked by eye to be twice the second. So I diveded each component of the third column by the corresponding component of q and tthey came out (more or less) the same.

Comment: I just noticed that its the sum of the three components 0.801.. + 0.53.. + .. =  1.603...

Comment: @AlessioPopovic since the sum of the components of q are 1